# Trouble giving php write permissions on windows

Tags: php, sqlite, iis-7.5, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to install a php forum software on my windows machine for testing purposes but im getting some permission denied errors when trying to create the sqlite3 database file.

I'm using IIS.

I tried setting the permissions to write in IIS Manager but that didn't do anything, And I tried right clicking on the directory and setting everyone to write permissions but still no luck.

Keep in mind security isn't really important here since im just setting this up for testing purposes.

Comment: What i've got on my production machine (not recommended) is giving everyone full permission into a sub directory, which is away from the main scripts.. Which I make PHP Write all necessary files too before manipulating into what I need them to do

Comment: I just want the php software to create a .db file in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test.db But it keeps throwing an error that says permission denied.